# Boolean modifier not showing in render

Tags: rendering, modifiers

[image]

how it looks in blender (top)
how it looks in the render (bottom)
[image]

Comment: May I suggest to verify that the Boolean modifier is "activated" both in "Real time/Display modifier in viewport" and "Render/Use modifier during render" ? These are the "monitor" and the "camera" icons in the modifier header.

Comment: @StefLAncien Since the modifier is enabled in render by default and newbies seldomly change something there, I would bet the problem is located elsewhere: the cutting object is made invisible in the viewport, but not render.

Comment: I have in fact verified that the render and viewport modifier sight is on. If the problem is in fact located elsewhere, I would probably need someone to point it out, since I am a newbie.